# How to move an app from phone to android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

A friend of mine used my phone to test an application he was creating in android studio. Long story short, the app is still on my phone and i was trying to figure out how i could take the app FROM my phone and export it onto Android Studio so that i could fiddle with it myself. I already asked my friend how to do that and he said he couldn't find anything on it so i thought it would be wiser to instead bring the situation to you fine folks.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the APK (compiled application file) from the phone may be possible under some  conditions, but importing it in to Android Studio is not.

The application exists on the phone in a compiled state, not as a Studio project.

There are tools to decompile Android applications, but if you were to decompile it all the way to the Java level, it may not compile back.

It is possible to make small tweaks if you decompile the application to [smali](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki), which is similar to assembly, but easier to read.

There are two ways to extract the APK from the phone:

1. If your phone is rooted, you can use an app like RootExplorere or you can use ADB running in root mode to pull the APK to the PC.

Use:

```
adb shell pm path app.package.name
```

to find out where the APK is stored, then use:

```
adb pull <path to apk>
```

to extract it to the PC.

2. If your phone is not rooted, but your friend did not disable backup of his app, you can create a backup and extract the APK from it.

Use this ADB command:

```
adb backup -apk -f backup.ab app.package.name
```

Then use [this tool](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) to unpack the backup file.

Once you have the APK, you can use [ApkTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to decompile, analyze and tweak it.

There are many more advance decompilers out there for Android, but your mileage may very.